# merge sort in javascript returns repeated elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do merge sort in JS and don't understand where I am messing up.  I want this to return [1,2,3,4] and it returns [1,1,1,4].

What part of it needs to change?

```
var array = [3,2,1,4]

function mergeSort(array) {
    if (array.length === 1) {
        return array
    } else {
        mid = Math.floor(array.length/2)
        left = mergeSort(array.slice(0, mid))
        right = mergeSort(array.slice(mid, array.length))
        return merge(left, right)
    }
}

function merge(left, right) {
    var leftIndex = 0
    var rightIndex = 0
    var sorted = []

    while (leftIndex < left.length && rightIndex < right.length) {
        if (left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex]) {
            sorted.push(left[leftIndex])
            leftIndex += 1
        } else {
            sorted.push(right[rightIndex])
            rightIndex += 1
        }
    }

    if (leftIndex < left.length) {
        sorted = sorted.concat(left.slice(leftIndex))
    } else if (rightIndex < right.length) {
        sorted = sorted.concat(right.slice(rightIndex))
    }
    return sorted
}

console.log(mergeSort(array))
```

Comment: if it should return just a sorted array like this `[1,2,3,4]`, why did you "invented" such a complicated function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping problem. You haven't declared the `left`, `right`, and `mid` variables so they are being treated as implicit globals and causing chaos.

Fixed:

```
function mergeSort(array) {
    if (array.length === 1) {
        return array
    } else {
        var mid = Math.floor(array.length/2)
        var left = mergeSort(array.slice(0, mid))
        var right = mergeSort(array.slice(mid, array.length))
        return merge(left, right)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine (with some declarations and semicolons).

```js
var array = [3, 2, 1, 4],
    result = mergeSort(array);

function mergeSort(array) {
    var mid, left, right;
    if (array.length === 1) {
        return array;
    } else {
        mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
        left = mergeSort(array.slice(0, mid));
        right = mergeSort(array.slice(mid, array.length));
        return merge(left, right);
    }
}

function merge(left, right) {
    var leftIndex = 0,
        rightIndex = 0,
        sorted = [];

    while (leftIndex < left.length && rightIndex < right.length) {
        if (left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex]) {
            sorted.push(left[leftIndex]);
            leftIndex += 1;
        } else {
            sorted.push(right[rightIndex]);
            rightIndex += 1;
        }
    }

    if (leftIndex < left.length) {
        sorted = sorted.concat(left.slice(leftIndex));
    } else if (rightIndex < right.length) {
        sorted = sorted.concat(right.slice(rightIndex));
    }
    return sorted;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```